# Android studio decodeStream returns image in landscape orientation

Tags: android, android-studio, bitmap, stream, orientation

In an android studio project, I get an image from the gallery using the `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` method. But the received bitmap is always in landscape orientation, so pictures with a height greater than the width are rotated by 90 degrees. How to solve the problem? Here is the getter code

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Context context, Uri resourceUri, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) throws IOException {
    InputStream imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(resourceUri);
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    imageStream.close();
    imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(resourceUri);
    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    //the bitmap is always in landscape orientation
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);
}

private static int calculateInSampleSize(
    BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of the image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize += 1;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```